# How to cast a column to decimal type in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

`tablesAA` has two columns, `amount` is `decimal (28,10)`, `amountscale` is `int`.

I need to cast the `amount` to `decimal [ (p[ ,s] )]`.

The 's' is dynamic from the `amountscale` column value, but the bottom code causes a syntax error.

So, how to do cast of `amount` depending on the `amountscale` value?

```
select 
    amount, amountscale,
    cast(amount as decimal(28, amountscanle)) as amount 
from tablesAA
```

Comment: Why would you want to cast an integer to decimal on the database level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, for a `cast()`, the scale and precision need to be constants.

If you just want the data output with a particular scale and precision, then you can convert them to a string using `str()` (documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx)):

```
select amount, amountscanle,
       str(amount, 28, amountscanle) as amount2
from tablesAA;
```

An alternative is the brute force approach:

```
select amount, amountscanle,
       (case when amountscanle = 0 then cast(amount as decimal(28, 0)
             when amountscanle = 1 then cast(amount as decimal(28, 1)
             when amountscanle = 2 then cast(amount as decimal(28, 2)
             . . . 
        end) as amount2
from tablesAA;
```